# PHP - getimagesize

Tags: php

I have a **very** strange error with getimagesize.

The code is pretty simple:

```
   if(!$path || !file_exists($path))
        return true;
   list($w, $h, $type) = getimagesize($path);
```

var_dump($path) returns the string "web/img/diaporama/diapo-call_1.jpg"

This code triggers: getimagesize(): Read error!

The file exists and it's a regular jpg file.

The strange thing is that if I insert: $path = 'web/img/diaporama/diapo-call_1.jpg'; between line 2 and 3, everything goes fine.

$path and 'web/img/diaporama/diapo-call_1.jpg' are exactly same, so this statement shouldn't make any difference. var_dump($path, 'web/img/diaporama/diapo-call_1.jpg') returns twice the same string..

I've tried on another server and there it runs normally.

It also runs without any problem if the path points to another file.

Any idea on what could be the problem here..?

Comment: What are the permissions on `web/img/diaporama/diapo-call_1.jpg`?

Comment: next to existance there's access rights / permissions.

Comment: 777. Indeed I should check the rights but anyway, if I force $path to 'web/img/diaporama/diapo-call_1.jpg' (which is already $path's value) it works. So I don't think it's realted to the file itself. Well, actually I'm not sure to what the error is related..

Comment: Where does this file come from? Is it uploaded and moved to this place or you placed it manually? If it's uploaded in a form, maybe you're just not saving it alright? ...

Comment: Are all the directories leading to `diapo-call_1.jpg` accessible to the webserver? Should at least be 775.

Comment: Make sure the filesize isn't 0 bytes.

Comment: i'd be guessing that something is wacky with the file; create a copy, point the `$path` to it, see what happens; this error also pops up when the file is blank

Comment: Arg. Figured out what was the problem.. I was looking at the wrong file and I gave up a bit too early..
Thanks for the answers anyway!